# Wer erfand das Land Narhalla?

Tags: etymology, dialect

"Liebe Närrinnen und Narrhallesen", ist eine der bekanntesten Begrüßungen bei Karnevalssitzungen. Narrhallesen sind die (männlichen) Bewohner des Landes Narhalla. Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrhallamarsch) ist der Begriff ein Zusammenschluss aus Narr und Walhalla und steht passenderweise für das Land des ewigen Karnevals.

Da ich den Begriff nur im Zusammenhang mit dem bekannten [Mainzer Narhallamarsch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-2DFOyUDAc) kenne und dieser anscheinend erst mit der Zeit zu diesem Namen kam, stellt sich mir die Frage wann das sagenumwobene Land Narhalla entdeckt wurde und wo es liegt. Alternativ wann und in welcher Karnevalsgegend der Begriff entstanden ist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Kurzantwort:**

> ...wann das sagenumwobene Land Narhalla entdeckt wurde und wo es liegt. Alternativ wann und in welcher Karnevalsgegend der Begriff entstanden ist.

Aktueller Kenntnisstand:

- Das sagenumwobene Land wurde spätestens 1843 (Nennung in der Literatur) entdeckt.
- Das Gebäude, das irgendwann zwischen 1841 und 1843 die *Narrhalla* aufnahm, befindet sich in der Augustinerstraße 55, 55116 Mainz.
- Es gab vielleicht auch vorher schon an einem anderen Ort ein Narrhalla, denn Fragensteller *mtwde* hat in einer Veröffentlichung  namens *Humoristischer Flaschenkeller* (1853) einen Vortrag von 1837 entdeckt:

  > **Ein Kapitelchen über die Liebe und die Ehe**
  >
  > Vortrag gehalten zur Fastnacht 1837 in der die Welt umstrahlenden Mainzer Narhalla, glorreichen Andenkens, abgedruckt in der Mainzer Narren-Zeitung

**Langfassung:**

Laut Google Ngram taucht der Begriff *Narrhalla* zuerst in den 1840er Jahren auf. Im ältesten gefundenen Dokument (von 1843) heißt es:

> Unter den übrigen Mittheilungen, deren die mainzer Karnevals-Signale eine so volle und reiche Garbe bieten, zeichnen sich noch besonders aus: der Prolog von F. Laske, gesprochen bei der Eröffnung der **Narrhalla**, im fünften Jahre der Narrheit; das Gedicht zur Einweihung des Falck'schen **Narhalla**-Tempels, vom Professor Niklas Müller; der Rangstreit der **Narrhalla**-Geister, ...

Zu dieser Zeit war die Narrhalla also ein Versammlungsort der Mainzer Karnevalisten.

Weiter unten wird der Ort als *großer, mit allegorischen Bildern und Verzierungen reich geschmückter Saal* im [Frankfurter Hof](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurter_Hof_(Mainz)), einem noch heute existierenden Gebäude, identifiziert.

[image: Bild des Frankfurter Hofs]
Im übrigen wurde bereits 1841, ebenfalls in Mainz, eine [Narrhalla - Carnevalszeitung für die Saison 1841](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrhalla_(Zeitung)) herausgegeben.

Comment: +1 Erstmal danke für die ausführliche Antwort. An ngram hatte ich überhaupt nicht mehr gedacht. Allerdings habe ich darüber nun [diesen Artikel](https://books.google.de/books?id=1CNDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA118&dq=%22narhalla%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs2oHXx-ngAhUQmrQKHSKQDAwQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22narhalla%22&f=false) gefunden. "Vortrag gehalten zur Fastnacht 1837 in der die Welt umstrahlenden Mainzer Narhalla". 4 Jahre vor der Eröffnung des Anbaus. Druck des Buches war jedoch erst 1853, evtl. passt das dann doch.

Comment: Wir erfahren daraus aber, wenn ich das nun richtig gelesen habe, dass gar kein **Land** gemeint ist, sondern ein Ort, und zwar wohl sogar ganz einfach ein Saal (in dem Fasnachtsveranstaltungen gehalten werden). Es liegt ja auch nahe, dass die Leute "Halla" als "Halle" lesen. - Ist die implizite Annahme in der Frage, es handle sich um ein *Land* also falsch?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Zur Beantwortung der Frage sollte man sich wohl an die offiziellen Vertreter Narrhallas wenden. Ich denke, dass die Narren die Behauptung, dass ihr Land nicht mehr als ein schnöder Saal ist vielleicht mit Humor, aber nicht allzu erfreut, aufnehmen würden. In der UN ist Narrhalla jedenfalls noch nicht.

Comment: Möglicherweise war Narhalla erst ein Saal, aber auch dieser Ort kann im übertragenen bildlichen Sinne schon ein Land darstellen, so sich die Narren da heimisch fühlen. Wer es ersonnen hat und warum kann wohl nicht mehr geklärt werden, aber "in Mainz", "um 1841" und "[Frankfurter Hof](https://www.mainz-congress.com/locations/frankfurter-hof/historie/)" sind mir ausreichende Fundstellen.